# What special issues are at play when loading a config file from the command prompt with DTExec?

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, ssis

If I run a package from the Management Studio, and specify a configuration file, everything works as expected.  I can also set the package to get it's config path from an environment variable, and that approach works as well.

However, if I try and run the package from the command prompt with DTExec I get the error:

> Cannot load the XML configuration
>   file. The XML configuration file may
>   be malformed or not valid.

The command I'm using to execute the package is:

```
dtexec /conf ConfigurationDemo.dtsConfig /f Package.dtsx
```

I am running the dtexec from the folder where these two files reside.  Is there an addtional switch or something that must used to get dtexec to behave the same was at the management Stduio in launching a package?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the config file is a valid XML file?  By the look of the error message there may be a problem with it.  When you run it from SSMS is it using the same config file?

Comment: Yes it's well formed xml --- it's also usable from the UI and from setting the config file path in an environment variable --- just not on the command line.

Comment: It sounds like your package is set up to look for the configuration in another location.  What is this value set to in your package?  \Package.Variables[User::PackagePath].Properties[Value]